# How to use Python webbrowser.open() to open a window on Background

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

I have a program that runs

```
`import webbrowser
 path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
 webbrowser.register('chrome', None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(path))
 chrome = webbrowser.get('chrome')
 chrome.open('chrome://newtab')`
```

Is there a way I can somehow make this program run in the background and prevent the window from popping up? I have tried `chrome.open('chrome://newtab', autoraise=False)`, but the program still does not open the window in the background.

Comment: By background, do you mean behind all the windows on a desktop or a background process?

Comment: I mean behind all of the windows, because it can be quite annoying if you are doing something while the program is running.

Comment: You mean not displaying the browser at all or just don't changing focus to the browser ?

Comment: @Cristiano I don't want the browser to pop up every time the program runs. So I don't want to change focus to the browser.

Comment: Any luck on this? Setting `autoraise=False` is still giving focus to the browser tab that is opened. On Windows using Google Chrome